# Inequality for a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Prove that if $f$ is a holomorphic function on the disc $D=D(z_0,R)$ and $0<r<R$ show that
       $$|f(z_0)|^2\leq \frac{1}{\pi r^2}||f||_D$$  Where $||f||_D=\iint_D|f(x+iy)|^2dxdy$

Comment: What is $c$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Prove that for every $0<r<R$ this formula holds :$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\iint_{ D(z_0,R)} f(x+iy) dxdy $$. Then you take squares and using basic inequalities you get your result. This is called  mean value for double integrals of a complex function.

Comment: Can you please provide some hints. or some web-links to prove the 'mean value for double integrals of a complex function'. Recently I saw this question in a problem-sheet and I stuck to solve this.

Comment: You can write $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $ and use Green's theorem on Cauchy Integral Formula , or you can look alternatively into Gamelin's book for this theorem.